# down lifting of variable coefficients for cover inequalities

Tags: valid-inequalities

Given a cover inequality of the form:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j\in C}x_j \leq |C|-1
\end{equation}

A lifted version of this inequality takes the following form:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j\in C}x_j+\sum_{j\in N\setminus C}\alpha_jx_j \leq |C|-1
\end{equation}

As long as $\alpha_j\geq 0$, $\forall j\in N\setminus C$, it follows that the lifted version of this inequality is stronger than the original cover inequality, because we add more arguments to the LHS without changing the RHS. The $\alpha_j$ coefficients can be obtained through a sequantial procedure.

This particular form of lifting is in some papers referred to as 'uplifting'. Equivalently, there exists another form of lifting known as 'down lifting'. For a given $D\subset N$, $N\cap C = \emptyset$, a downlifted version of the cover inequality:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j\in C\setminus D}x_j+\sum_{j\in D}\beta_jx_j \leq |C|+\sum_{j\in D}\beta_j-1
\end{equation}

In contrast to the uplifted version, in the downlifted version we modify the RHS. As such, it is not obvious to me:

- why/when is this down lifted inequality stronger than the original cover inequality?

For a given $j\in D$, when $x_j=1$ the $\beta_j$ terms of the LHS and RHS cancel each other out and we obtain the orignal cover inequality. However, when $x_j=0$, the RHS remains larger and we obtain an inequality that seems weaker?

- when would you apply down lifting?

Comment: See section II.2 ("Valid inequalities for the 0-1 knapsack polytope") of Nemhauser and Wolsey, *Integer and combinatorial optimization*. This section describes it quite well. Hoffman and Padberg recommend to set $D=\{i\in C:x_i^*=1\}$. Then first up-lift variables with $x_i^*>0$, where $i\not \in C$ (this strengthens the inequality), next down-lift variables in $D$ (makes room for more variables with positive coefficients), finally up-lift variables with $x^*_j=0$ where $j\not\in C$ (strengthen again).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the purpose of lifting is to obtain a strong inequality in a higher dimensional space than the original inequality. A cover inequality is only in very rare cases a facet defining inequality for the knapsack polytope. Even the extended cover inequalities define facets in only rare cases (see Proposition 2.3, section II.2 of [Nemhauser and Wolsey](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118627372)).

The general theory is as follows: Suppose that $S\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ and $S^\delta=S\cap\{x\in\{0,1\}^n:x_1=\delta\}$ for $\delta\in\{0,1\}$. Furthermore, assume that \begin{equation}
\sum_{j=2}^n\pi_jx_j\leq \pi_0
\end{equation}
is a facet defining inequality for $\text{conv}(S^0)$, then if $S^1\neq \emptyset$ and $\alpha_1=\pi_0-\max\{\sum_{j=2}^n\pi_jx_j:x\in S^1\}$ it can be shown that \begin{equation}
\alpha_1x_1+\sum_{j=2}^n\pi_jx_j\leq \pi_0
\end{equation}
is facet defining for $\text{conv}(S)$. If $\sum_{j=2}^n\pi_jx_j\leq \pi_0$ on the other hand is a facet defining for $\text{conv}(S^1)$ and $S^0\neq\emptyset$ then
\begin{equation}
\gamma_1x_1+\sum_{j=2}^n\pi_jx_j\leq \pi_0+\gamma_1
\end{equation}
is a facet defining inequality for $\text{conv}(S)$ if $\gamma_1=\pi_0-\max\{ \sum_{j=2}^n\pi_jx_j:x\in S^0\}$ (these claims are proven in Proposition 1.1. and 1.2. in section II.2 of Nemhauser and Wolsey). Due to these results, if we can prove a given inequality is facet defining for a restricted version of the original polytope ("restricted polytope" here means the polytope in a lower dimensional space obtained by fixing some variables to either zero or one), then up- and down-lifting can be used sequentially to generate a facet defining inequality for the original high-dimensional polytope.

The last result needed is stated in Corollary 2.4 in section II.2. of Nemhauser and Wolsey: If $C\subseteq\{1,...,n\}$ is a minimal cover for the knapsack $S=\{x\in\{0,1\}:\sum_{j=1}^n a_jx_j\leq b\}$ and $(C_1,C_2)$ is a partition of $C$, with $C_1\neq \emptyset$, then $\sum_{j\in C_1}x_1\leq \vert C_1\vert-1$ is a facet defining inequality for $\text{conv}(S(C_1,C_2))$, where
\begin{equation}
 S(C_1,C_2)=\{  x\in\{0,1\}^{\vert C_1\vert}: \sum_{j\in C_1}a_jx_j\leq b-\sum_{j\in C_2}a_j  \}
\end{equation}

With this result, we can sequentially apply down-lifting of the variables in $C_2$ and up-lifting of the variables in $\{1,...,n\}\setminus C$ in order to get a facet defining inequality for $\text{conv}(\{x\in\{0,1\}:\sum_{j=1}^n a_jx_j\leq b\})$.